# React-Native textInput adding numbers adds digits instead

Tags: react-native, sum, textinput

I have two input fields that takes numbers i add both and display. the problem is when i enter 40 , my total field must display 40. But it is displaying 4+40 = 44 . and in next input field if i add 30 it is taken as 3 + 30 and my total field is showing 44 +33 = 77 instead of 70

This is my implementation. I know its a simple thing but i went through many forums before asking this question.

```
    const [ival, setIval] = useState(0);  // state to hold sum
      const handleInput = val => {      // handles input
        let tmp = parseInt(val) + parseInt(ival);  // adds curr state and input
        setIval(tmp);
      };
    <TextInput
              style={[{height: 40, borderWidth: 1}]}
              value={ival}
              onChangeText={text => handleInput(text)}
            />
            <TextInput
              style={[{height: 40, borderWidth: 1}]}
              value={ival}
              onChange={text => handleInput(text)}
            />
            <Text>{ival}</Text>     // displayes sum
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is - taking into account a new number every time a value is entered in the text input

This should work -

```
 const [ival, setIval] = useState(0);  // state to hold sum
const [input1, setInput1] = useState('');
const [input2, setInput2] = useState('');

      const handleInput1 = val => {      // handles input
       setInput1(val) 
        setIval(ival+parseInt(val));
      };

 const handleInput2 = val => {      // handles input
       setInput2(val) 
        setIval(ival+parseInt(val));
      };
    <TextInput
              style={[{height: 40, borderWidth: 1}]}
              value={input1}
              onChangeText={text => handleInput1(text)}
            />
            <TextInput
              style={[{height: 40, borderWidth: 1}]}
              value={input2}
              onChange={text => handleInput2(text)}
            />
            <Text>{ival}</Text>     // displayes sum
```